# Read a text file and form a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have file data.txt , below python  code reads a text and forms dictionary.

file: data.txt

```
10/20   vinay   
05/31   hunachyal
11/23   mine

bday_list = {}


infile = open("data.txt")
for line in infile:
    List_array = [w.strip() for w in line.split("\t")]
    bday_list[List_array[0]] = List_array[1]
#    print line

print bday_list


 Op: {'11/23': 'mine', '10/20': 'vinay', '05/31': 'hunachyal'}
```

Similarly  how to get dictinaory  for the below file in the format as shown in OP

file

```
  10/20 Name    vinay   phone   +91094xxx   
  05/31 Name    hunachyal   phone +91jndjxx
  11/23 Name    mine    phone +92jdddxxx

  OP:

  {'11/23': {'Phone': '+91kexxx', 'Name': 'mine'}, '10/20': {'Phone': '+919xxxx', 'Name': 'vinay'}, '05/31': {'Phone': '+9194xxxx', 'Name': 'hunachyal'}}
```

Or Is there any method in python to form data base where i can easily fetch data .

Comment: All the answers works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this

```
bday_list = {}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as R:
    for line in R:
        l = line.strip().split()  # split the line to list
        bday_list[l[0]] = {k:v for k,v in zip(l[1::2], l[2::2])}
```

---

PS,
If you are using `infile = open(...)` and not `with open() as infile:` to work with a file handle, you should remember to `close` the file handle afterward.

Answer (score 2):

try the following approach:

```
>>> data = """10/20 Name    vinay   phone   +91094xxx   
...   05/31 Name    hunachyal   phone +91jndjxx
...   11/23 Name    mine    phone +92jdddxxx
... """
>>> 
>>> result = {}
>>> 
>>> for line in data.splitlines():
...     dataList = line.split()
...     result[dataList[0]] = {dataList[1]: dataList[2], dataList[3]: dataList[4]}
... 
>>> result
{'11/23': {'Name': 'mine', 'phone': '+92jdddxxx'}, '10/20': {'Name': 'vinay', 'phone': '+91094xxx'}, '05/31': {'Name': 'hunachyal', 'phone': '+91jndjxx'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:)

```
infile = open("data.txt")
for line in infile:
    List_array = [w.strip() for w in line.split("\t")]
    bday_list[List_array[0]] ={"Phone":List_array[1],"Name":List_array[2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
f = open('filename.txt').readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in f]

new_dict = {i[0]:{i[b]:i[b+1] for b in range(1, len(i), 2) if b+1 < len(i)} for i in f}

print new_dict
```