# Python: Convert multi-line text into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text, multiline

I have a textfile of the format (well, it is much less structured, but the parts I need follow the below idea):

```
[ThisShouldBeAKey]
Value1=yes
Value2=no
Value3=fancywords
Value4=numbers

[ThisShouldBeAnotherKey]
Value2=true
Value3=333
Value5=qqq
```

I want to convert this file into a dictionary, so that I can easily compare certain values of certain keys. E.g., retrieve Value8 and Value9 of [Key1] and [Key100].

I imagine I can retrieve Value8 and Value9 by simply iterating over a textdump of the [key], and using startswith() or other string functions to retrieve what I want. So, although you could (ideally?) make a nested dictionary, I don't >think< I necessarily require this.

However, I even have trouble simply getting a dictionary of [Key]:Value1Value2Value3AllthevaluesTextdump. I have tried a few things on my own, I have tried the suggestion here ( [In Python, how do I read a file into a dictionary with multiple line entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330853/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-into-a-dictionary-with-multiple-line-entries) ) and alterations on it, but I always run into a problem with for-loops, while-loops, or the file simply not being read properly.

How would you recommend doing this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check [configparser module from standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: Dictionaries can only have one value per key, so you would need an array to hold all the values or a nested dictionary if you want the custom indexes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and write INI file with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python3)

Answer (score 0):

Loop on each line and detect the starting square bracket to start a new group. Use split to get key and value on other lines to update the current group:

```
result = dict()
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("["):
        result[line.strip("[] ")] = group = dict()
    elif "=" in line:
        group.update([line.strip().split("=",1)])

print(result)
{'ThisShouldBeAKey': {'Value1': 'yes', 'Value2': 'no', 
                      'Value3': 'fancywords', 'Value4': 'numbers'}, 
 'ThisShouldBeAnotherKey': {'Value2': 'true', 'Value3': '333',
                            'Value5': 'qqq'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through the lines with [`<dict>.setdefault`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/setdefault) and [`<str>.split`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split)

```py
filepath = 'x.txt' #<-- name of / path to your file

with open(filepath, 'r') as f: fLines = f.read().splitlines() #<-- read file
kCur = '__no_parent_key__' #<-- set a default for if 1st line isn't a [key]
result = {kCur: {}} #<-- initiate

for l in fLines:
    if '=' in l: _, l = result[kCur].update([l.split('=', 1)]), ''# [l empty -> skip]

    l = l.strip()
    if not l: continue #<-- skip empty lines

    kCur = l[1:-1] if (l[0], l[-1]) == ('[', ']') else l #<-- trim [] 
    result.setdefault(kCur, {})

# remove '__no_parent_key__' if empty:
if not result['__no_parent_key__']: del result['__no_parent_key__']
```

For your sample snippet, `result` will look like

> ```py
> { 
>   'ThisShouldBeAKey': {'Value1': 'yes', 'Value2': 'no', 'Value3': 'fancywords', 'Value4': 'numbers'},
>   'ThisShouldBeAnotherKey': {'Value2': 'true', 'Value3': '333', 'Value5': 'qqq'} 
> }
> ```

---

You could also use a reference dictionary <sup>(like `kwList` below)</sup> and [`ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/6146136) to parse the values a bit further.

```py
kwList = {'true':True, 'false':False, 'null': None, 'none': None}
def try_eval(literalStr:str, kwRef=kwList):
    if literalStr.strip().lower() in kwRef: 
        return kwRef[literalStr.strip().lower()]
    try: return ast.literal_eval(literalStr)
    except: return literalStr
```

To make use of `try_eval`, change the *`if '=' in l:..`* block in my suggested solution to

```py
    if '=' in l: 
        k, v = l.split('=', 1) 
        result[kCur][k] = try_eval(v)
        continue
```

then `result` will look like

> ```py
> { 
>   'ThisShouldBeAKey': {'Value1': 'yes', 'Value2': 'no', 'Value3': 'fancywords', 'Value4': 'numbers'},
>   'ThisShouldBeAnotherKey': {'Value2': True, 'Value3': 333, 'Value5': 'qqq'} 
> }
> ```

[Note the changes in `Value2` and `Value3` of `ThisShouldBeAnotherKey`.]